# Tic Tac Toe 1D array and my 'Check_for_win' function

Tags: c, arrays, function

I have created a simple Tic Tac Toe program in C. Everything is working OK (still needs a little clean-up) except for my check_for_win function. I'm not sure if I am declaring it in the correct spot, i.e. the main function. I switched it over to the player_input function because logically that would make more sense to me, i.e. checking for a win after each player moves, but still to no avail.

This is my syntax:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void menu()
{
    int choice;
    do
    {
        printf("Main Menu\n\n");
        printf("   1. Play Game\n");
        printf("   2. Quit Game\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: board();
                break;
            case 2: printf("Quitting program!\n");
                exit(0);
                break;
            default: printf("Invalid choice!\n");
                break;
        }
    } while (choice != 1);
}

int board() {
    printf("\n\n");
    printf(" 1 | 2 | 3 \n");
    printf("--------------\n");
    printf(" 4 | 5 | 6 \n");
    printf("--------------\n");
    printf(" 7 | 8 | 9 \n");
}

/*int display() {
printf("//   1 | 2 | 3\n");
printf("//   ---------\n");
printf("//   4 | 5 | 6\n");
printf("//   ---------\n");
printf("//   7 | 8 | 9\n\n\n");
}

int gameboard(int board[9]) {
printf("//   %d | %d | %d \n", board[0], board[1], board[2]);
printf("//   ---------\n");
printf("//   %d | %d | %d \n", board[3], board[4], board[5]);
printf("//   ---------\n");
printf("//   %d | %d | %d \n\n\n", board[6], board[7], board[8]);
}*/

void player_input(char gameboard[])
{
    int i;
    int playerX, playerO;
    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        printf("\nPlayer 1, please select a square by entering a number between [1 - 9]:\n\n");
        scanf("%d", &playerX);
        ///playerX = playerX - 1;
        display_board(gameboard, playerX, playerO);
        printf("\nPlayer 2, please select a square by entering a number between [1 - 9]:\n");
        scanf("%d", &playerO);
        ///playerO = playerO - 1;
        display_board(gameboard, playerX, playerO);

    }
    return(playerX);
    return(playerO);

}

void display_board(char gameboard[], int playerX, int playerO) {
 ///INPUT FOR PLAYER O
    if(playerO == 1)
    {
        gameboard[0] = 'O';
    }
    else if(playerO == 2)
    {
        gameboard[1] = 'O';
    }
    else if(playerO == 3)
    {
        gameboard[2] = 'O';
    }
    else if(playerO == 4)
    {
        gameboard[3] = 'O';
    }
    else if(playerO == 5)
    {
        gameboard[4] = 'O';
    }
    else if(playerO == 6)
    {
        gameboard[5] = 'O';
    }
    else if(playerO == 7)
    {
        gameboard[6] = 'O';
    }
    else if(playerO == 8)
    {
        gameboard[7] = 'O';
    }
    else if(playerO == 9)
    {
        gameboard[8] = 'O';
    }

    ///INPUT FOR PLAYER X
    if(playerX == 1)
    {
        gameboard[0] = 'X';
    }
    else if(playerX == 2)
    {
        gameboard[1] = 'X';
    }
    else if(playerX == 3)
    {
        gameboard[2] = 'X';
    }
    else if(playerX == 4)
    {
        gameboard[3] = 'X';
    }
    else if(playerX == 5)
    {
        gameboard[4] = 'X';
    }
    else if(playerX == 6)
    {
        gameboard[5] = 'X';
    }
    else if(playerX == 7)
    {
        gameboard[6] = 'X';
    }
    else if(playerX == 8)
    {
        gameboard[7] = 'X';
    }
    else if(playerX == 9)
    {
        gameboard[8] = 'X';
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    printf(" %c | %c | %c \n", gameboard[0], gameboard[1], gameboard[2]);
    printf("--------------\n");
    printf(" %c | %c | %c \n", gameboard[3], gameboard[4], gameboard[5]);
    printf("--------------\n");
    printf(" %c | %c | %c \n", gameboard[6], gameboard[7], gameboard[8]);

}

void check_for_win(char gameboard[])
{

    if (gameboard[0] == gameboard[1] == gameboard[2] == 'X')
        {
        printf("Player X has WON!");
        }
    else if (gameboard[3]==gameboard[4]==gameboard[5]=='X')
        {
        printf("Player X has WON!");
        }
    else if (gameboard[6]==gameboard[7]==gameboard[8]=='X')
        {
        printf("Player X has WON!");
        }
    else if (gameboard[0]==gameboard[3]==gameboard[6]=='X')
        {
        printf("Player X has WON!");
        }
    else if (gameboard[1]==gameboard[4]==gameboard[7]=='X')
        {
        printf("Player X has WON!");
        }
    else if (gameboard[2]==gameboard[5]==gameboard[8]=='X')
        {
        printf("Player X has WON!");
        }
    else if (gameboard[0]==gameboard[4]==gameboard[8]=='X')
        {
        printf("Player X has WON!");
        }
    else if (gameboard[2]==gameboard[4]==gameboard[6]=='X')
        {
        printf("Player X has WON!");
        }


    else if (gameboard[0]==gameboard[1]==gameboard[2]=='O')
        {
        printf("Player O has WON!");
        }
    else if (gameboard[3]==gameboard[4]==gameboard[5]=='O')
        {
        printf("Player O has WON!");
        }
    else if (gameboard[6]==gameboard[7]==gameboard[8]=='O')
        {
        printf("Player O has WON!");
        }
    else if (gameboard[0]==gameboard[3]==gameboard[6]=='O')
        {
        printf("Player O has WON!");
        }
    else if (gameboard[1]==gameboard[4]==gameboard[7]=='O')
        {
        printf("Player O has WON!");
        }
    else if (gameboard[2]==gameboard[5]==gameboard[8]=='O')
        {
        printf("Player O has WON!");
        }
    else if (gameboard[0]==gameboard[4]==gameboard[8]=='O')
        {
        printf("Player O has WON!");
        }
    else if (gameboard[2]==gameboard[4]==gameboard[6]=='O')
        {
        printf("Player O has WON!");
        }
    else
        {
        printf("THE GAME HAS COME TO A DRAW.");
        }
}

int welcome() {
 printf("ELEC 1520 Programming Assignment 1\n");
    printf("Programmer: Anonymous\n\n");
    printf("Press the enter key to start playing....\n");
    char enter = 0;
    while (enter != '\r' && enter != '\n') {
            enter = getchar();
    }
}

int main () {
    char gameboard[] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
    welcome();
    menu();

    ///player_input();
    ///process_input(board);

    int playerX=0;
    int playerO=0;

    display_board(gameboard, playerX, playerO);

    printf("\n\nRULES\n");
    printf("Player 1 is X and goes first.\n");
    printf("Player 2 is O.\n");
    printf("Please select a square by choosing a number between [1 - 9]:\n\n");

    player_input(gameboard);

    check_for_win(gameboard);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (gameboard[0] == gameboard[1] == gameboard[2] == 'X')
```

doesn't do what you are hoping to. Due to operator precedence, it is evaluated as

```
if ( ((gameboard[0] == gameboard[1]) == gameboard[2]) == 'X')
```

Regardless of what the values of `gameboard[0]`, `gameboard[1]`, and `gameboard[2]` are, the expression `((gameboard[0] == gameboard[1]) == gameboard[2]) == 'X'` will always evaluate to false since `((gameboard[0] == gameboard[1]) == gameboard[2])` will be either true (1) or false (0).

In other words, the above `if` is equivalent to:

```
if (0)
```

To fix your logic, use

```
if (gameboard[0] == 'X' &&
    gameboard[1] == 'X' &&
    gameboard[2] == 'X')
```

Update the other `if/else if` statements similarly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I've changed the code per your suggestions, and everything seems to running smoothly except for two things now: I placed the check_for_win(gameboard) at the end of the display_board function. I need to make it so that if, for example, Player 1 puts his 'X' on square 5, then Player 2 cannot overwrite this with his 'O'. When the last "else" statement ("this game has come to a draw") isn't removed, the game immediately goes to a draw.

Comment: @user72680, I think it will be better to fix your code and ask that question in a new post.

Answer (score 0):

instead of double equal to(==) use double ampersand(&&) in (gameboard[0]==gameboard[1]==gameboard[2]=='O')